# How to copy a range and omit blank cells?

Tags: vba, excel

In column A on sheet 1 there are 3000 cells that I need copied at 350 cells each. My current Macro is copying everything just fine until I get to the end and it copies blanks. Is there a way to include a "cell is blank do nothing" code into my macros?

Sorry if this sounds uneducated, I'm just starting on learning macro.
Here is a copy of the current macro, the rest of the macro is the same as this just with increasing numbers by 350.

```
Sub Copy_Bins_1_350()
    If Range("D12").Value <> "!" Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Range("D12").Value = "!" Then
        Sheets("sheet1").Select
        Range("B2:B351").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("B2").Select
        Sheets("sheet2").Select
        Range("E12").Select
        With Selection.Font
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Union` to form your own range of non empty cells and then copy them.

Also [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Try this (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, rngCopyFrom As Range, rng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BIN LIST PASTE")
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BIN LIST COPY")

    Set rng = wsI.Range("B2:B351")

    For Each aCell In rng
        If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) <> 0 Then
            If rngCopyFrom Is Nothing Then
                Set rngCopyFrom = aCell
            Else
                Set rngCopyFrom = Union(rngCopyFrom, aCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not rngCopyFrom Is Nothing Then _
    rngCopyFrom.Copy wsO.Range("E12")

    With wsO
        lRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("E12:E" & lRow)

        With rng.Font
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, this copies my information into another page where as I only need it to just copy for me everything but the empties. The stuff I am copying will be pasted into a whole other program and this program messes up if there are blanks. I tried messing with it too and reading your link, its very very interesting, thank you for providing it to me.

I am thinking of using something along the lines of selecting a range and putting an If:Then command in it. EG. If blank then Do not copy. Or something of that caliber. Im just not sure how to make that into the excel language

Comment: Yes it will copy it to `BIN LIST COPY` sheet. Didn't you want to copy it there?

Comment: Actually no, even though the page is titled in such a manner I really just need the bins copied to paste them in another program later on.

Comment: In that case change the line `If Not rngCopyFrom Is Nothing Then _
    rngCopyFrom.Copy wsO.Range("E12")` to `If Not rngCopyFrom Is Nothing Then rngCopyFrom.Copy` and then the data is stored in the clipboard. Paste it wherever you want :)