# Type mismatch error on copying ranges.

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make this work, but it says `Type mismatch`. Any help on what I am doing wrong? (I am very new to this)

```
Sub Copy_paste_XP()

Dim wsI As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range, rngCopyFrom As Range, rng As Range
Dim lRow As Long

Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Move containers XP")

Set rng = ("E2:E500")

For Each aCell In rng
    If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) <> 0 Then
        If rngCopyFrom Is Nothing Then
            Set rngCopyFrom = aCell
        Else
            Set rngCopyFrom = Union(rngCopyFrom, aCell)
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not rngCopyFrom Is Nothing Then rngCopyFrom.Copy

Range("K2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Set rng = ("F2:F500")

For Each aCell In rng
    If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) <> 0 Then
        If rngCopyFrom Is Nothing Then
            Set rngCopyFrom = aCell
        Else
            Set rngCopyFrom = Union(rngCopyFrom, aCell)
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not rngCopyFrom Is Nothing Then rngCopyFrom.Copy
Range("K501").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is highlighted when it throws an error? Also, I see that you repeated your code *twice*, in essence. Can you explain as well what you want to do? I believe there is a much more efficient way. :)

Comment: which line have the `Type Mismatch`?

Comment: Sub Copy_paste_XP() <--- Is highlighted in Yellow

Comment: E2:E500 <---- This is selected for me.

I am trying to make it copy e2:e500 and paste by value in K2 then copy f2:f500 and then paste them by Value in K501 while excluding 0's or blanks

Comment: ah, you forgot to reset your `rngCopyFrom`. Add this line `Set rngCopyFrom = Nothing` before you start the next loop. If not, `rngCopyFrom` will contain both `E2:E500` and `F2:F500` range address which will trigger the error. You cannot copy multiple selection.

Comment: Same error... Maybe I am pasting it in the wrong spot? I am really sorry, I am very bad at this. I tried putting it under Next, set rng (2nd one)

Comment: I understand what its trying to do, but when I reset it it still gives me that error

Comment: try what Siddart pointed out in his answer :). That should fix it. Or re-write the whole thing using BK201's logic. :D

Comment: To reinforce @SiddharthRout's comment, kindly check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738373/can-i-make-this-macro-more-efficient-or-faster/20754562#20754562) out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you are not setting the variables correctly. You used `Set rng = ("E2:E500")` when it should be `Set rng = wsI.Range("E2:E500")`.

Also, the macro can be made more flexible. The following code should work:

```
Sub CopyNotZero(SrcRng As Range, DestRng As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range, RngToCopy As Range
    For Each Cell In SrcRng
        If Cell.Value <> 0 And Len(Cell.Value) <> 0 Then
            If RngToCopy Is Nothing Then
                Set RngToCopy = Cell
            Else
                Set RngToCopy = Union(RngToCopy, Cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
    If Not RngToCopy Is Nothing Then
        RngToCopy.Copy
        DestRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
    Set RngToCopy = Nothing
End Sub
```

Use it like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet: Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Move containers XP")
    With wsI
        CopyNotZero .Range("E1:E500"), .Range("K2")
        CopyNotZero .Range("F1:F500"), .Range("K501")
    End With
End Sub
```

This will skip all cells with `0` value or no values at all.

***Screenshots:***

**Set-up:**

[image]

**Result after running `Test()`:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

To call this macro everytime you paste to `$A$2`, the following code will work (modify accordingly):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        CopyNotZero Range("A1:A500"), Range("K2")
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just curious... Why `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Oops. Also, forgot something. Editing now.

Comment: Also `RngToCopy.Copy DestRng` will fail if `RngToCopy` is nothing. You need the extra check `If Not rngCopyFrom Is Nothing Then RngToCopy.Copy DestRng`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Forgot that he wanted values as well, so I changed the above to use `PasteSpecial` rather than just `Paste`. :)

Comment: + 1 it's all good now :) `Set RngToCopy = Nothing` can also move inside the IF/Endif ;)

Comment: Thanks, @SiddharthRout! Wondering though. Which is best practice in this case, doing a catch-all and setting it outside, or include it in the loop since technically it hasn't existed anyway if the `IF` condition is not met? :/

Comment: This worked great for me, thank you.One last question?
If I wanted this to run automatically as soon as I put information in A2:A500 how would I approach that? Would it look something like this?

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Target.Address = "A:2" Then

Call MyMacro

End If

Comment: @Forbidden: Check my edit above. You were pretty close, but your `.Address` is wrong, and you actually don't need `Call`. Just make sure the `CopyNotZero` macro is saved in a module in the same workbook. :) Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it helped you. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I will, thanks again. I appreciate your patience with me!

Comment: No worries. This is also an exercise for me. Just look at how many times @SiddharthRout corrected me. Lol. :) Thanks for accepting and all the best. :)

Answer (score 0):

> E2:E500 <---- This is selected for me. I am trying to make it copy e2:e500 and paste by value in K2 then copy f2:f500 and then paste them by Value in K501 while excluding 0's or blanks – Forbidden 9 mins ago
>
> Set rng = ("E2:E500")

You are missing the word `Range`. Change it to

```
Set rng = wsI.Range("E2:E500")
```

**EDIT**

Similarly for `Set rng = ("F2:F500")`

Also this seems to be a followup from your [PREV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602875/how-to-copy-a-range-and-omit-blank-cells) question. I see you are still using `.Select` ;)

Comment: Haha yeah it is. You method worked for me, except for some reason it does copy 0's and for some other reason it pastes in K and L.